# Higher order function on lists Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I created a function `p` that checks if the square of a given value is lower than `30`.
Then this function is called in an other function (as argument) to return the first value inside a list with its square less then 30 ( if p is true, basically I have to check if the function `p` is `true` or `false` ).

This is the code :

```
let p numb = 
let return = (numb * numb) < 30 in return

let find p listT =
  let rec support p listT =
    match listT with
    | []-> raise (Failure "No element in list for p")
    | hd :: tl -> if p hd then hd
    else support p tl in
    let ret = support (p listT) in ret

let () =
  let a = [5;6;7] in
  let b = find p a in print_int b
```

But it said on the last line :

```
Error: This expression (p) has type int -> bool
   but an expression was expected of type int -> 'a -> bool
   Type bool is not compatible with type 'a -> bool
```

However, I don't think I'm using higher order functions in the right way, I think it should be more automatic I guess, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that

```
let return = x in return
```

can replaced by

```
x
```

Second, your original error is on line 10

```
support (p listT)
```

This line makes the typechecker deduce that the `p` argument of `find` is a function that takes one argument (here `listT`) and return another function of type `int -> bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to look at your problem, which is as @octachron says.

If you assume that `p` is a function of type `int -> bool`, then this recursive call:

```
support (p listT)
```

is passing a boolean as the first parameter of `support`. That doesn't make a lot of sense since the first parameter of `support` is supposed to be a function.

Another problem with this same expression is that it requires that `listT` be a value of type `int` (since this is what `p` expects as a parameter). But `listT` is a list of ints, not an int.

A third problem with this expression is that it only passes one parameter to `support`. But `support` is expecting two parameters.

Luckily the fix for all these problems is exremely simple.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, because this is my first time dealing with higher order functions so I'm trying everything to make them work eheheh. But one question, is listT input for p ? I'm assuming no, p and listT are the arguments of support right?